# Weierstrass Caratheodory on open interval

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

[image]

I have been working on this question for a while now, and if I have understood it correctly shouldn't the answer be that $\phi_{c}=f'(x)$ for all $x \in (a,b)$ as the function $f$ , is now said to be differentiable on all of $(a,b)$ and so $\phi_{c}$ is continuous on all of $(a,b)$... I am not too confident about this answer, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should try some examples.

Answer (score 1):

Given $f$ differentiable in $\ ]a,b[\ $ and a point  $c\in\ ]a,b[\ $, the function $\phi_c$ alluded to in the question can be written as follows:
$$\phi_c(x)={f(x)-f(c)\over x-c}={1\over x-c}\int_c^x f'(t)\ dt\qquad(x\ne c)\ .$$

Take $x>c$. Your question can then be formulated as follows: Can the average of $f'$ on the interval $[c,x]$ be equal to the value of $f'$ at the right endpoint of this interval? This is certainly impossible when $f'$ is strictly monotone on $[c,x]$.

In order to obtain an interesting example we therefore consider the function $f(x):=x^3$, whose derivative is not monotone. Choosing $c=-2$ and $x=1$ we get
$$\phi_{-2}(1)={1^3-(-2)^3\over 1-(-2)}=3=f'(1)\ ,$$
as desired.

In the above example $c$ and $x$ were carefully chosen. If you want $$\phi_c(x)=f'(x)\qquad\forall\ x\in\ ]a,b[\ ,$$
then  $f$ has to be a polynomial of degree $\leq1$, because it then satisfies the differential equation
$$f(x)-(x-c)f'(x)=f(c)\qquad(x\in\ ]a,b[\ )\ .$$

Comment: What about something like the function $f(x)=sin(x)$ its derivative $f'(x)=cos(x)$ is not monotone but if we pick $c=-\pi$ and $x= \pi /2$  the function $\phi_{-\pi}(\pi /2) \ne f'(\pi /2)$